# Seeking error in OSMF

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, http, seek, osmf

I have a HTTP video player built using Adobe's OSMF and I am experiencing a strange behavior when trying to seek within a subclip.

The player requests data from the server using URL like `"http://videoserver.com/video.flv"` to get the full video, and appends `"?begin=123456"` to request a subclip starting at 123456 bytes offset.

Whenever I try to seek within a loaded subclip, the playhead just drops to the start of the subclip and the video plays from there. Although both `mediaPlayer.canSeek()` and `mediaPlayer.canSeekTo(newtime)` return true.

Any feedback is more than appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

OSMF automatically seeks to nearest keyframe. Try encoding your video keyframe/sec.
read more here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/osmf-media-player.html

Comment: I have little control over how the media is encoded. I'll try this, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Also, check that provided parameter ?begin expects time as offset value. It might also be that it expects bytes as offset value.

Comment: The offset is bytes, not seconds, I know this for sure =)